# Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated. Fix for this specific instance

Tags: php

I am trying to fix a specific instance of function `split` being depreciated. Here is the original line:

```
list($file, $link, $text) = split("\|", $imagedb[$i]);
```

I tried

```
list($file, $link, $text) = explode ("\|", $imagedb[$i]);
```

and

```
list($file, $link, $text) = preg_split("/|/", $imagedb[$i]);
```

neither worked, what this script does is take a line from a text file like this:

```
21.jpg|http://www.kelleysisland.com/crafts/|Crafts Lakeview Lane
```

and creates a grid of random photos that are linked, with linked titles under them here:

```
http://kelleysisland.com/where-to-stay/cottages-and-homes
```

Here is the complete script if that helps:

```
$sFilename = "imagedb2.txt";
$sTemplate = "template.html";
$thumburl = "http://www.kelleysisland.com/thumbs";
function show_thumbs() {
    global $sFilename, $sTemplate, $thumburl;
    $imagedb=file($sFilename);
    shuffle($imagedb);
    $i=0;
    while($i<count($imagedb)) {
        $d=1;
        $template=file_get_contents($sTemplate);
        while(preg_match_all("/<% image$d %>/", $template, $matches)) {
            list($file, $link, $text) = split("\|", $imagedb[$i]);
            $template=preg_replace("/<% image$d %>/", "<a href=\"$link\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"$thumburl/$file\" border=0></a>", $template);
            $template=preg_replace("/<% text$d %>/", "<a href=\"$link\" target=\"_blank\">$text</a>", $template);
            $d++;
            $i++;
        }
        echo $template;
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to escape `|` character in `explode` or `split` function. `explode ("|", $imagedb[$i]);` is enough. but in your `preg_split` you have escape `|` like `preg_split("/\|/", $imagedb[$i]);`

Comment: Thanks! That solved it!! Just using: `explode ("|", $imagedb[$i]);`